# CSS make default direction rtl instead of ltr

Tags: css, magento, right-to-left

Is there any way to make default direction of the whole CSS file RTL instead of LTR? If not, is there any tool that insert 'direction:rtl' in each CSS tag? My CSS file have 20000 lines of code and it's to hard to change all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily the best solution, but an option is to use this [universal css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors): `*`

```
* {
    direction:rtl;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, you save my time. but i have a problem that i have a few items must be in ltr as default

Comment: @snake If it's only a few items, you can add a class to all the elements that need to be ltr and add the direction style to that class, that will override the universal selector.

Comment: I can't override it even by using !important

Comment: @snake, this answers the question you asked, and you should thus accept it. (Technically, setting just `html { direction: rtl }` or  `body{ direction: rtl }` is sufficient for setting the *default*.) If you have some *other* question, please ask it separately and provide sufficient HTML and CSS code to actually reproduce it. Any setting will override one that uses `*`, so in your case, there must be something very special if an override does not work. Show what you actually tried. In a new question.

Comment: @Andy thanks . and I will post my css file in separate question